# Get value from another #document JavaScript !Doctype

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I get value from another iframe?

When I inspecting the website and I click on this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="1" value="q"›
```

And I type this to the console:

```
document.getElementsByName("3")[0].value
```

I can get the value:

'e'

But if I click outside from iframe, and I check the value I get this result:
VM89205:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
at :1:49

Looks like I have to click inside if I want get the value. Is it possible to get the value without every time click inside?

```
<iframe name="frame" id="frame" src="TEST.html?token=asdasdasd" style="display: none;"> ==$0 
    #document
      <html>...</html>
     </iframe>                                                                                    
    <form name="apple" id="apple" method="get" action="test.htm?token=asdasdasd" target="dialog">  <input type="hidden" name="1" value="q"›
      <input type="hidden" name="1" value="q"›
      <input type="hidden" name="2" value="wm> 
      <input type="hidden" name="3" value="e"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="4" value="r"› 
      <input type="hidden" name="5" value="e> 
      <input type="hidden" name="6" value="z"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="7" value>
      <input type="hidden" name="8" value="u"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="9" value="i"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="10" value>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access an iframe's content from outside the iframe (provided, it's not an external domain), use `document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document.getElementsByName("3")[0].value;`

Answer (score -1):

Add name tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="1" name="q" value="q"›
```

---

and then type this to get the value

```
var v = document.getElementById("q").innerHTML;
console.log(v);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this way now working. The code not allowed me give 2 names. And when i try to get the value this error message pop up:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')
    at <anonymous>:1:51

Comment: `q` is still in an input element and wouldn't have `innerHTML`. And like @zsolti900 said, duplicate name attributes aren't allowed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).